# The auto-complete box is not showing list on webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xslt, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have put one textbox on webpage,which is autocomplete box.but when i write something in autocomplete textbox,it doesn't list anything even though it has list.While debugging the code,the list is generated by XML and it is showing on HTML page also,but it doesn't show in AutoComplete Box.

```
var lst_source = $("#tdStaffVolunteerList"); var lst_options = $("option", lst_source);
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#txtstaffvolunteerlist").autocomplete({
                source: lst_options.map(function() {
                    return $(this).text();
                }).get()
            });
        });
```

where 'txtstaffvolunteerlist' is autocomplete list under 'tdStaffVolunteerList'

Comment: [this](http://jsfiddle.net/8vMUm/) works for me, what's different in yours?